# Was wäre eine gute Übersetzung für "Mince Pie" oder "Pickles"?

Tags: english-to-german

Was wäre eine gute Übersetzung für "Mince Pie" oder "Pickles"?
(nicht Saure Gurken)

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what you mean by pickles.

Answer (score 2):

"[Pickle](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=Pickle)" alleine wird in der Regel mit "Essiggurke" übersetzt. In der Kombination "[Mixed Pickles](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=Pickles)" wird der Ausdruck (soweit mir bekannt) so belassen.

"Mince Pie" ist eine englische Spezialität. So wie man im Englischen "schnitzel" verwendet, würde ich im Gegenzug dieses Wort nicht übersetzen  wollen. Fremdwörter haben ihre Existenzberechtigung ;)

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man mit jemandem spricht, der nicht weiß, was das ist, kann man so eine erklärende Halbübersetzung benutzen, wie

> Pickles, sozusagen Essiggemüse

als Parallelbildung zu Essiggurken, und

> Mince Pie, also gefüllte Trockenfrüchte-Törtchen

Das enthält zwar noch nicht so richtig das weihnachtliche daran, also wenn man das betonen will:

> Mince Pie, das sind mit Trockenfrüchten gefüllte Weihnachtstörtchen

Das sollte einem so ungefähr die richtige Idee geben. 
Im Falle von Mince Pie würde ich aber nach dieser Einführung das Wort *Mince Pie* weiterbenutzen, weil es einfach kürzer ist. Bei *Essiggemüse* ist es mehr geschmackssache, ob man im Folgenden lieber wieder *Pickles* sagt, weil das andere ja auch hinreichend kurz ist. Mir persönlich ist es manchmal lieber, deutsch klingende Wörter zu benutzen, insbesondere, wenn es sonst viele englische Wörter in einem Satz wären, weil ich mich sonst irgendwann mit der Aussprache verhaspel wie die gute Frau aus dem einen [Loriotsketch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvF0zzDG_EI).

Nur noch ein Hinweis zur Verwendung: Solche Spontanübersetzungen sollte man immer in "Anführungszeichen" setzen, im gesprochenen durch Betonung und Verwendung von *dieser*, also ein Beispielsatz ohne Wahrheitsgehalt:

> In unserem Bed&Breakfast gab es morgens immer Pickles, also so Essiggemüse, und dieses labberige Toastbrot. [...]. Und an dem einem Tag hatten wir dieses "Essiggemüse" sogar auf der Pizza.